# Is there a good name for "classic" .NET?

Tags: .net, naming

So, as Microsoft has created many forks and branches off of .NET, there have been a few different product names come up:

- Silverlight
- .NETCore/WinRT/.Net for Windows Store Apps
- .NET for Windows Phone/CoreCLR
- .NET Micro Framework
- .NET Compact Edition

However, what do you call the traditional .NET we all know and love? You can't call it Desktop .NET probably, because it also runs on servers, and that might imply you're using that client-profile thing. .NET for PC seems unusual. You can't really just say "this is a product for .NET" because then people might assume that includes support for one of the other frameworks

Does Microsoft have an official "name" for the traditional .NET that runs in Windows PCs?

Comment: AFAIK it is just vanilla ".NET Framework", without any Compact/Micro/Phone or WinRT extension.

Comment: @DocBrown that's what I thought, but it's hard to distinguish. Imagine a product where you say "we support .Net for Windows Phone, .Net for Windows Store, and .Net Framework". The last bit seems really weird to say

Answer (score 6):

[Microsoft's own terminology](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/vstudio/hh487283.aspx) labels this category as *".NET Framework (Windows desktop and server)".*

It's a little long-winded but I don't see how you can be any less ambiguous. It clearly excludes Silverlight, Windows Phone, Mono, etc.

As far as the "Client Profile", the *and server* phrasing should take care of that; unless an application specifically labels itself as desktop-only, I would assume that it is targeted to the full framework and not the Client Profile.